# AngularJS Routes: losing content on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I am creating a directory using AngularJS routes and I have run into a problem. Currently I have several departments in my directory all of which have have their own HTML templates and all use the same controller. The template files however are all identical the only difference are these lines here.

```html
 <div id="content" data-ng-init="contentCtrl('MG')">
        <div class="deptName">
            <h2>Management</h2>
        </div>
   
   //rest of content goes here
   
   </div>
```

So it occurred to me that I could probably just use one template file and pass in the relevant JSON file for each department like so.

```html
 <div id="content" data-ng-init="contentCtrl(activeDepartment)">
        <div class="deptName">
            <h2>activeDepartment</h2>
        </div>
   
   //rest of content goes here
   
   </div>
```

So far this solution is "working". However, when I refresh the page it is blank. I think I know WHY this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it. I think it is happening because when I refresh the page the activeDepartment variable was never set(it is set when you click the department on the homepage). The only way I can think to fix this is if there was some way to declare a variable in my route provider along the lines of

```js
$routeProvider
            .when('/MG', {
                controller: 'teammateController',
                templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
                activeDepartment = management
            })
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to do this, am I going about it the wrong way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how your existing code works even once. The resolve parameter should look like `resolve: function() {return 'management'}`.

Comment: @Amy are you referring to the final code snippet? Because I know that is way wrong, I just meant it as an example of what I am trying to do, I am not familiar with resolve: are you saying it could be structured like this `.when('/MG', {
                controller: 'teammateController',
                templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
                resolve: function() {return 'management'}
            })`   Sorry for the ambiguity, I should have specified that was not  "working" code

Comment: Yes, it should be structured like that. You said you're losing the content on refresh, which to me ought to mean that it was working before you hit the refresh button. I don't understand why what you had would work if you did or did not hit the refresh button.

Comment: Wouldn't ng-storage be a good idea for session based sensitive information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "I wish I could do it like this" code is very close to how you actually do do it!  You want:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/MG', {
    controller: 'teammateController',
    templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
    resolve: {
      activeDepartment: function() {
        return 'Management';
      }
    }
  })
```

The activeDepartment key defined in resolve can then be injected as a dependency in your controller, so you can get at it in the scope:

```
app.controller("teammateController", function(activeDepartment) {
  $scope.deptName = activeDepartment;
  (...etc...)
}
```

and finally in your template,

```
<div class="deptName"><h2>{{deptName}}</h2></div>
```

(Typically `resolve` will return something more interesting than a bare string, of course; basically each key you put in the resolve object will be injectable as a dependency to any directive, controller, service etc where you happen to need it.)

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for! I am heading out of the door now but I will try this solution as soon as I can and see what I get.

Comment: Ok, so I am working on implementing this but I have run into an error message: ReferenceError: activeDepartment is not defined when I try to declare `$scope.deptName = activeDepartment();`. I think it is because I am missing the second part of your answer, I am unsure where to place (activeDepartment) in my controller, this is my current controller. `app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location) {` I tried putting it where I "thought" it went and that only made matters worse, any suggestions?

Comment: Try including activeDepartment as one of the dependencies on the controller, as shown above... `app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location, activeDepartment)`

Comment: I tried that but it gave me a different error (TypeError: activeDepartment is not a function). I put a console log `controller: 'teammateController',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                resolve: {
                    activeDepartment: function() {
                        console.log("working");
                        return 'home'
                    }` And it is firing, then the error message displays, so the function is being called. Is there a way to declare the variable inside resolve:

Comment: Egad!  Many apologies, careless typo on my part; it should be `$scope.deptName = activeDepartment` in the controller, not `activeDepartment()`.

Comment: I've corrected the answer (and added a bit more explanation.) Apologies again for sending you on a goose chase...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101345/discussion-between-colton-williams-and-daniel-beck).